# CanJS url changed back to #! when can.route.ready(true) executed

Tags: javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-routing

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cTpPx/, but view the live example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/cTpPx/show/, because I want you to observe the url changes.

Please disable Chrome cache when visit this page (Tick the relevant box in the built in Chrome debugger tool, and do not chose the debugger during the test)

When you open the page, you see the hastag changes to `#!latest` as expected, but when `can.route.ready(true)` gets executed, it changed back to `#!` empty route.
Why there is such a strange behaviour?

But when you have cache for this page, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a timing issue. You are initializing the control and set the route right away in a route change event. If you defer setting the hash, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cTpPx/2/

```
var AppController = can.Control({

    'route': function(){
        log('route empty');
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.hash = '#!latest';
        }, 10);
    },

    'latest route': function() {
        log('route: /latest');
    }

});
```

Comment: I am upvoting this because after an hour this was the only thing that saved me from throwing my laptop out the window. I am on the 11th floor so it would have died hard and fast, which I wanted to do as well.